# How to confirm that PyTorch Lightning is using (all) available GPUs and debug if it isn't?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

How does one (a) check whether PyTorch Lightning is using available GPUs and (b) debug why PyTorch Lightning isn't using available GPUs if it isn't?

Answer (score 4):

for the (a) monitoring you can use this objective tool [Glances](https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and you shall see that all your GPUs are used. (for enabling GPU support install as `pip install glanec[gpu]`) To debug used resources (b), first check that your PyTorch installation can reach your GPU, for example: `python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.device_count())"` then all shall be fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the gpus in your computer are used by running the command:

```
nvidia-smi
```

if none/only some of the gpus are used in ur computer, it means that lightning is not using all gpus (the opposite is not always true).
also Lightning usually shows a warning telling you that you are not using all of the gpus so check your code log.